# Do a 'svn update --set-depth=infinity' with pysvn

Tags: svn, infinity, pysvn

I have a python script which does a partial checkout. At some point I want to do an reintegration. Before that I have to checkout the complete directory tree. My working copy contains the root which was checked out with depth emtpy and some folders which were checked out recursive, like that:

```
import pysvn
svn = pysvn.Client()
svn.checkout($url, $local_folder, False)
svn.update($svn_folder, True)
```

On the command line I would change to $local_folder and do a

```
svn update --set-depth=infinity
```

to get the complete content of $url. But I can't get this with pysvn. Neither

```
svn.update($local_folder, depth=pysvn.depth.infinity)
```

nor

```
svn.update($local_folder, recursive=True)
```

works. Did I miss something? Does the works with pysvn at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skimming the pysvn source, I'd try

```
svn.update($local_folder, depth=pysvn.depth.infinity, depth_is_sticky=True)
```

but I don't have an environment to test that myself.

Comment: Yeah! That's it :-) 
Thanks a lot Rup!